# Suppose there is $log_{a}^{*}x$ and $\log_{b}^{*}x$ then $\log_{a}^{*}x = O(\log_{b}^{*}x)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Consider two $a,b \in R$. So my question is : 
Suppose there is exist $log_{a}^{*}x$ and $\log_{b}^{*}x$ then $\log_{a}^{*}x = O(\log_{b}^{*}x)$

**NB**: $\log^{*}{n} = 1+\log^{*}{\log{n}}$
Actually I have my own proof , but I guess there is some mistakes. So what do you think about it?
Upd.

Comment: I think something must serve as a variable here, as for fixed $\;a,b\;$  the big O notation deson't make much sense...

Comment: @Joanpemo $a,b$ could be a variable

Comment: Thank you: which one of them? Both? If both, how would you go about looking what happens when the variables tend to infinity? First one, then other or what?

Comment: @Joanpemo that doesn't matter. So my question is about it

Comment: I think it does. We define $\;f(x)=\mathcal O(g(x))\;$ when $\;x\to\infty\;$ if $\;|f(x)|\le M|g(x)|\;$ for all $\;x>R\;$ , for some $\;R\in\Bbb R_+\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo I made a mistake... One minute

Comment: @Joanpemo that an update version.. Sometimes I become absentminded

Comment: Now I understand the question. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the change of base property of logarithms, we have that

$$\frac{\log x}{\log a}=\color{red}{\log_ax}=\color{red}{\mathcal O(\log_bx)}=\mathcal O\left(\frac{\log x}{\log b}\right)\iff \frac{\left|\frac{\log x}{\log a}\right|}{\left|\frac{\log x}{\log b}\right|}\le M\;,\;\;M=\text{some constant}$$

but

$$\frac{\left|\frac{\log x}{\log a}\right|}{\left|\frac{\log x}{\log b}\right|}=\frac{|\log b|}{|\log a|}\implies\;\text{it is enough to choose}\;\;M=\frac{|\log b|}{|\log a|}$$

and we've finished.

Comment: Actually I don't see any connection with my problem

Comment: I hope I wrong ..

Comment: @Open Did you read my comments below your question? There I commented about hte definition of big O notation...Perhaps you have *another* definition of big O?

Comment: no I agree with big O notation. I don't see how it connect with $log^{*}$

Comment: @openspace Then apparently you're definining $\;\log^*\;$ in a particular way I've never seen. I thought all through that you used * to separate the logarithm from its argument...In your N.B. you use * in both sides, so that is **not** a definition...or is it?

Comment: that's a definition . Read about iterated logarithm

Comment: I'd rather won't. Good luck.